# Prevent first click on mobile dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made this little site: http://www.physiotherapie-im-friedrichshain.de
and was made aware that the subpages can not be navigated to on mobile phones, as the main menu item loads a new page directly when "pressed".

I have searched for the last couple hours and couldn't find a solution which works.

How can I prevent the first click on a menu item with subpages to load, and make it just open the submenu or anything at all?

Thanks,

Emil

Comment: what are you using to show submenu on hover? psuedo classes? js? jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by removing the link from the tabs:

For example replace:

```
<a href="http://www.physiotherapie-im-friedrichshain.de/unser-angebot/">Unser Angebot</a>
```

with

```
<a href="#">Unser Angebot</a>
```

If you want to prevent it only the first time, as BG101 suggested, then on click of `.menu-item-has-children` you can save the url in a custom attribute and change the href attribute to `#`

```
<a href-temp="http://www.physiotherapie-im-friedrichshain.de/unser-angebot/" href="#">Unser Angebot</a>
```

On the eventual sequential click you can just swap the values of `href-temp` and `href`.

Comment: I think on second click Gruenbaer whats the user to go to `/unser-angebot/`.

Answer (score 0):

Try binding a click handler that opens the menu if it's closed, but opens the page if it's open:

```js
$('.submenu_link').on('click', function(event) {
  if (!$(this).next('.submenu').is(':visible')) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('.submenu').show();
    $(this).next('.submenu').focus();
    return false;
  }
});

$('.submenu').on('blur', function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
.submenu {
  display: none;
}

.submenu_link {
display: inline-block;
padding: 5px;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://google.com" class="submenu_link">Search Options</a>
<ul class="submenu" tabindex="-1">
  <li>Advanced Search</li>
  <li>Get Lucky</li>
</ul>
```